# GORM Persistence Event Listener

Tags: ajax, grails, grails-orm

if anybody deletes, updates or creates  domain objects, I wanted to make an ajax call to send the new domain object to the view so that the tables is being actualized with the new values. How can I do that?

I tried to create a custom persistence event listener first.

```
public class MyCustomPersistenceListener
    extends AbstractPersistenceEventListener {


protected MyCustomPersistenceListener(Datastore datastore) {
    super(datastore)
}

@Override
protected void onPersistenceEvent(AbstractPersistenceEvent event) {
    switch (event.eventType.toString()) {
        case "PreInsert":
            println "PRE INSERT ${event.entityObject}"
            break
        case "PostInsert":
            println "POST INSERT ${event.entityObject}"
            break
        case "PreUpdate":
            println "PRE UPDATE ${event.entityObject}"
            break;
        case "PostUpdate":
            println "POST UPDATE ${event.entityObject}"
            break;
        case "PreDelete":
            println "PRE DELETE ${event.entityObject}"
            break;
        case "PostDelete":
            println "POST DELETE ${event.entityObject}"
            break;
        case "PreLoad":
            println "PRE LOAD ${event.entityObject}"
            break;
        case "PostLoad":
            println "POST LOAD ${event.entityObject}"
            break;
    }
    //println "${event.eventType}"
}

@Override
boolean supportsEventType(Class<? extends ApplicationEvent> aClass) {
    return true
}
```

}

Then in Bootstrap.groovy I added my application listener to the grails application context.

```
def grailsApplication

def init = { servletContext ->
    def applicationContext = grailsApplication.mainContext

   grailsApplication.mainContext.eventTriggeringInterceptor.datastores.each { k, datastore ->
        applicationContext.addApplicationListener new MyCustomPersistenceListener(datastore)
    }
}
```

What's the best way here? Where to make the ajax calls to the view?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use spring or default Web sockets. I wrote a couple of plugins that have demo sites using default websocket jssh and boselecta. Depends on your preference for default they will give you an idea

Answer (score 0):

> Where to make the ajax calls to the view?

Ajax calls are not made to the view.  An Ajax call would be initiated by the client (typically a web browser).  You could orchestrate the behavior you want with other technologies like web sockets for example but the answer to the question as asked is you can't.

Comment: Ok thx. I'd rather to call service methods within Domain Classes... How to make trigger a client sided javascript function?

Comment: "How to make trigger a client sided javascript function?" - If you want to trigger an event in the client from an event on the server, you will need to use a technology like web sockets.